# Interaction between .net plugins of the different unmanaged processes

Tags: c#, .net, windows

OS Windows, .NET Framework.

I run two unmanaged applications which are using the .Net in own working:
it is, for example, MS Excel and MS Word. In each of this process work my some .Net plugins: my_excell__net_plugin and my_word__net_plugin.

1. How can I to interact between my .net plugins, which are working in the different unmanaged processes? The .NET Framework version is the same in the both plugins.
2. Can I do it, if the .NET Framework version will be different?

Comment: Use the standard process interop mechanisms in .NET, like file, named pipe, socket, wcf.  Do note how unwise this is, a plugin is *not* in control of the process so it can terminate at any time and you have no guarantee whatsoever that the other party is present.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to use the sokets.